# Is there an advantage to running JRuby if you don't know any Java?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

I've heard great things about JRuby and I know you can run it without knowing any Java. My development skills are strong, Java is just not one of the tools I know. It's a massive tool with a myriad of accompanying tools such as Maven/Ant/JUnit etc.

Is it worth moving my current Rails applications to JRuby for performance reasons alone? Perhaps if I pick up some basic Java along side, there can be so added benefits that aren't obvious such as better debugging/performance optimization tools?

Would love some advice on this one.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think you pretty much nailed it.

JRuby is just yet another Ruby execution engine, just like MRI, YARV, IronRuby, Rubinius, MacRuby, MagLev, SmallRuby, Ruby.NET, XRuby, RubyGoLightly, tinyrb, HotRuby, BlueRuby, Red Sun and all the others.

The main differences are:

- portability: for example, YARV is only officially supported on x86 32 Bit Linux. It is not supported on OSX or Windows or 64 Bit Linux. Rubinius only works on Unix, not on Windows. JRuby OTOH runs *everywhere*: desktops, servers, phones, App Engine, you name it. It runs on the Oracle JDK, OpenJDK, IBM J9, Apple SoyLatte, RedHat IcedTea and Oracle JRockit JVMs (and probably a couple of others I forgot about) and also on the Dalvik VM. It runs on Windows, Linux, OSX, Solaris, several BSDs, other proprietary and open Unices, OpenVMS and several mainframe OSs, Android and Google App Engine. In fact, on Windows, JRuby passes more RubySpec tests than "Ruby" (meaning MRI or YARV) itself!
- extensibility: Ruby programs running on JRuby can use any arbitrary Java library. Through JRuby-FFI, they can also use any arbitrary C library. And with the new C extension support in JRuby 1.6, they can even use a large subset of MRI and YARV C extensions, like Mongrel for example. (And note that "Java" or "C" library does not actually mean written in those languages, it only means with a Java or C API. They could be written in Scala or Clojure or C++ or Haskell.)
- tooling: whenever someone writes a new tool for YARV or MRI (like e.g. memprof), it turns out that JRuby already had a tool 5 years ago which does the same thing, only better. The Java ecosystem has some of the best tools for "runtime behavior comprehension" (which is a term I just made up, by which I mean much more than just simple profiling, I mean tools for deeply understanding what exactly your program does at runtime, what its performance characteristics are, where the bottlenecks are, where the memory is going, and most importantly *why* all of that is happening) and visualization available on the market, and pretty much all of those work with JRuby, at least to some extent.
- deployment: assuming that your target system already has a JVM installed, deploying a JRuby app (and I'm not just talking about Rails, I also mean desktop, mobile, other kinds of servers) is literally just copying one JAR (or WAR) and a double-click.
- performance: JRuby has much higher startup overhead. In return you get much higher throughput. In practice, this means that deploying a Rails app to JRuby is a good idea, as is running your integration tests, but for developer unit tests and scripts, MRI, YARV or Rubinius are better choices. Note that many Rails developers simply develop and unit test on MRI and integration test and deploy on JRuby. There's no need to choose a single execution engine for everything.
- concurrency: JRuby runs Ruby threads concurrently. This means two things: if your locking is correct, your program will run faster, and if your locking is incorrect, your program will break. (Unfortunately, neither MRI nor YARV nor Rubinius run threads concurrently, so there's still some broken multithreaded Ruby code out there that doesn't know it's broken, because obviously concurrency bugs can only show up if there's actual concurrency.)
- platforms (this is somewhat related to portability): there are some amazing Java platforms out there, e.g. the Azul JCA with 768 GiBytes of RAM and 864 CPU cores specifically designed for memory-safe, pointer-safe, garbage-collected, object-oriented languages. Android. Google App Engine. All of those run JRuby.

Answer (score 7):

I would modify what Peter said slightly. JRuby *may* use more memory compared to standard Ruby, but that's usually because you're doing the work in a single process what would take several processes with Ruby.

You should try the `Rails.threadsafe!` option with a single JRuby runtime (for example, the Trinidad gem with the `--threadsafe` option). We've heard several stories where it gives you great performance and low memory usage, while leveraging multiple CPU cores with a single process.

Answer (score 5):

JRuby is one of the few implementations that uses native threads.  So if you care to do some multithreading, go for it.

As far as hosting is concerned, you have to put your app in some sort of java container, which I personally find to be far less straightforward than using something like passenger (for Rack apps)

I use JRuby for an app as we communicate over JMS and it works fine, but if I wasn't using any Java I would certainly stick to CRuby.  My biggest beef is that in testing, running tests takes forever with JRuby as you have to spin up a VM each time you run them.  This makes it a lot harder to TDD as it's a significant hit on your testing time.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but on a point of pedantry I believe that MRI 1.9 now also uses native threads.  However, it has a great big lock (the GIL) around the which effectively makes a lot of code single-threaded in practice.  It would still be fair to say that JRuby is one of the few implementations that *takes advantage* of native threads :-)

Answer (score 5):

Jruby has advantages if you're on Windows. It supports 64 bits and you can use a lot of proprietary databases with standard JDBC drivers.

Comment: For some reason I could never get Oracle drivers to work properly :-(

Comment: @Steven: Do you think the same company owning both Oracle and Java will help?

Answer (score 3):

The latest releases are significantly faster than Ruby but also use significantly more memory.  If that is your only reason for using JRuby, I wouldn't bother unless you have a specific performance need that it solves, simply because, while it is pretty popular, it is less standard for hosting and less people use it as compared to standard Ruby.  That being said, there are many other reasons to use JRuby such as a need for interoperability with existing Java code and the need to deploy in environments where Java has been "blessed" by the operations department and Ruby has not.