# What reasons would I have for not using JRuby over MRI/YARV?

Tags: ruby, jruby

In [Is there an advantage to running JRuby if you don't know any Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927615/is-there-an-advantage-to-running-jruby-if-you-dont-know-any-java), people were suggesting using JRuby if you just want a better implementation of Ruby than "Ruby" (MRI/YARV).

What potential reasons would you have for not using JRuby?

Ones that have been mentioned by others are:

1. Performance for short programs. JRuby is described as faster for longer programs, but having a longer initialization time. Workarounds are discussed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224178/how-to-improve-jruby-load-time).
2. C extensions: JRuby supports some, [but not all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927615/is-there-an-advantage-to-running-jruby-if-you-dont-know-any-java/3928025#3928025), C extensions that are used with MRI/YARV.
3. Concurrency as a two-edged sword. [There's non-thread-safe code out there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927615/is-there-an-advantage-to-running-jruby-if-you-dont-know-any-java/3928025#3928025) that people haven't discovered because the most popular implementation doesn't have true concurrency.
4. JRuby [can use more memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927615/is-there-an-advantage-to-running-jruby-if-you-dont-know-any-java/3927834#3927834).
5. JRuby has [decided not to do](http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/DifferencesBetweenMriAndJruby) certain things CRuby does. This includes continuations (which I think are deprecated in CRuby anyway), and fork. They also have a different native endian, and time precision.
6. JRuby [doesn't enable ObjectSpace](http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/PerformanceTuning) by default.

Potential reasons I have include:

1. Libraries you use may not be designed to run under JRuby. For example, BioRuby, which has 127 watchers and 60 forks on GitHub, had a [minor incompatibility](http://github.com/bioruby/bioruby/issues/issue/6) with JRuby.
2. Fear, Uncertainty, and Doubt about using a less popular implementation. I know JRuby passes RubySpec better than CRuby, but RubySpec is not yet complete.

Are there any other reasons you wouldn't use JRuby?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, while it comes pre-installed on Macs I don't always install Java on my Linux machines.

As an aside, [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) should probably be mentioned here as the canonical way to juggle multiple (8 or more?!) different Ruby interpreters.

Answer (score 0):

JRuby doesn't seem to give [$SAFE](http://blog.headius.com/2007/04/what-would-i-will-i-change-about-ruby.html) a high priority. The blog post is from 2007, but I haven't come across any changes since then.